# exception handler causes any performance de-gradation?

Tags: c#, exception

If I have a piece of code which does something like this.

```
try
{
...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
throw;
}
```

The fact that in catch block we are only doing a throw, I cannot seem to find any advantage of this particular exception handler. Are there any peformance issues this unnecessary catch cause to codeflow?

Comment: Performance aside, it's just plain silly, too.

Comment: i know; I see someone doing it. Want to make sure i understand all possible side-effects of it

Comment: I would imagine so, but I'd recommend writing a simple console app benchmark if you want to find out the magnitude.  This smells like dead code to me, though; perhaps it was added to help with debugging a particular issue (set a breakpoint on the throw), then the issue was resolved and the code was left behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *may* cause a performance hit when an exception is thrown - although if an exception is being thrown often enough for that to be a problem, it was probably *already* a problem beforehand (exceptions should normally *not* cause a significant performance hit, because they should only be used in exceptional circumstances).

It *may* cause a performance hit even when an exception *isn't* thrown, as it may prevent a method from being inlined.

It *does* cause a readability/simplicity issue - and that's the primary reason to get rid of it. Maybe it was there for debugging purposes, but there's no reason to have it in checked-in code. It's ugly and pointless, so should definitely be removed.

Comment: +1. Was about to post something similar, but as usual a Jon Skeet answer is vastly superior.

Comment: Thanks Jon. What I want to understand is what happens to the code in a try-catch blocks vs same code NOT in a try-catch block

Comment: @SilverlightStudent: When the catch block just throws, there won't be much semantic difference - other than whether you can put a breakpoint there.

Comment: let's say if no exception is thrown. In that case, does compiler or runtime has to do any extra work for the code that is in try block?

Comment: @SilverlightStudent: Well the generated IL will be larger due to the catch block, which may prevent inlining at JIT time. (Indeed, the JIT may decide to not inline anything with a catch block.) But as I pointed out, that *isn't* why you should get rid of it - you should get rid of it because it's ugly, crufty, unnecessary code.